# Podman move data containers to another host

Tags: permissions, podman

I have nextcloud installed in a Podman pod. I want to move the data of nextcloud and database on another host. How should I make the archive and how to use podman unshare so that the other place has the same non-root rights

i tried archive up the folders but after moving and installing nextcloud it doesn't have the right permissions